# With paper_trail gem how to skip changes between nil and blank?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord, paper-trail-gem

**TL;DR:** How can one skip changes between `nil` and `blank` in paper_trail?

I use https://github.com/airblade/paper_trail to log data changes in several `ActiveRecord` objects. Some changes are useless from my customers' point of view, so I need to ignore all changes between `nil` and `blank` (empty string).

`paper_trail` doesn't seem to have such option. You can skip certain fields with `:skip` option. Can you pass in a Proc that would "decide" to skip changes conditionally?

Answer (score 2):

Your can add a proc to define a new version should be saved or not, the code should be:

```
class ExampleModel < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_paper_trail :if => Proc.new { |t| t.attr_1.present? && t.attr_2.present? }
end
```

By the way `:unless` was also supported! This works for PaperTrail >= 4.0

Comment: Thank you for the variant! It kind of works, but that way I'm going to have either list all fields in all my paper_trail models, or use self.columns or something. I can have a module and a method in it that would accept the array of columns though - not bad! I'm going to upvote this, but not mark as the accepted answer yet.

Answer (score 0):

I know this is pretty old, but I recently had this issue and I ended up monkey-patching it...

```
# config/initializers/paper_trail.rb

    module PaperTrail
      module Events
        class Base
          def notable_changes
            changes_in_latest_version.delete_if { |k, _v|
              !notably_changed.include?(k) or _v.all?{|v|v.blank?}
            }
          end
        end
      end
    end
```